# Array assignment works in ThisWorkbook module, but not Sheet1 module

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is meant to copy data from one `Workbook`, paste it at the bottom of another, then remove duplicates from the destination file.

I originally developed the code in the `ThisWorkbook` module, but I when added a button to Sheet1 to trigger the macro, it kicks out when trying to assign the data from the source file into the `newData` array.

This feels like an issue related to the behaviour of Excel, which I'm less familiar with.

Edit: I've also experimented with cutting out the array and simply using the "Transfer" method of having `Cells.Value` in the destination file be assigned the `Cells.Value` of the source file. It works fine for moving the data, but then the `.removeDuplicates` simply does nothing. It doesn't through an error, but it just doesn't remove any of the duplicates.

Thanks!!!

```
For i = 0 To 16
    colArray(i) = i + 1
Next i

location = "R:\dummyLocation"

destLastRow = Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks.Open (location & "SOURCE_FILE.xlsx")
Workbooks("SOURCE_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Activate
sourceLastRow = Workbooks("SOURCE_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
newData = Workbooks("SOURCE_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(sourceLastRow, 17))
Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Activate
Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A:Q").NumberFormat = "@"
Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(destLastRow + 1, 1), Cells(destLastRow + sourceLastRow - 2, 17)) = newData
destLastRow = Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set cbuRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(destLastRow, 17))
cbuRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(colArray), Header:=xlYes
Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Save
Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Close
Workbooks("SOURCE_FILE.xlsx").Close
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Kicks out". Does it error? If so, what is the error. Best guess without that bit of information is that your `Cells()` inside your `Range()` in the line `ewData = Workbooks("SOURCE_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(sourceLastRow, 17))` are based on the ActiveSheet. It's like saying `newData = Workbooks("SOURCE_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1), activeSheet.Cells(sourceLastRow, 17))` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, it's a Run-time 1004 error.

Comment: @Jnevill I'm not sure why that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually now that I look through your code you do Activate that workbook. So even though it's not properly qualified, it will probably work fine. Can you toss a breakpoint on that `newline=` line and then see what the value of your `sourceLastRow` variable is in your `Locals` pane. Perhaps that value is less than `3`?

Comment: so `sourceLastRow` is the appropriate value, 52848.

Comment: And if I change the `newData` assignment to simply `Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(sourceLastRow, 17))` without the book/sheet qualifiers, it doesn't throw the error, but then `newData` is empty.

Comment: It's late in the day and I'm probably not at my best here. How about using `Set newData =` instead of just `newData =` since we are setting the `newData` range object here. If that's it, I apologize for overlooking that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195651/discussion-between-sethw-and-jnevill).

Comment: tried using `Set` to no avail, but also it's a `variant`, not a range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% what is causing this, but it could be plenty of things. In case it may help, here's a quick rewrite of this snippet using variables to track the sheets instead of relying on `.activate` and hoping for the best:

```
For i = 0 To 16
    colArray(i) = i + 1
Next i

location = "R:\dummyLocation"


'Source work
Dim sfWB as Workbook
Set sfWB = Workbooks.Open (location & "SOURCE_FILE.xlsx")
Dim sfWS as Worksheet
Set sfWS = sfWB.Worksheets(1)
sourceLastRow = sfWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'This is a variant, but here it will act like a range, so `Set` should be used:
Set newData = sfWS.Range(sfWS.Cells(3, 1), sfWS.Cells(sourceLastRow, 17))

'destination work
Dim dfWS as Worksheet
Set dfWS = Workbooks("DESTINATION_FILE.xlsx").Worksheets(1)

dfWS.Range("A:Q").NumberFormat = "@"
destLastRow =sfWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Copy source data to destination
newData.Copy Destination:=dfWS.Cells(destLastRow + 1, 1)

'get new last row
destLastRow = dfWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Set cbuRange range object and remove dupes
Set cbuRange = dfWS.Range(dfWS.Cells(1, 1), dfWS.Cells(destLastRow, 17))
cbuRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(colArray), Header:=xlYes

'Save and exit
dfWB.Save
dfWB.Close
sfWB.Close
```